# Key in dictionary gets deallocated before I can use it

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, memory-management

I am pretty new to objective-c.

Basically what happens is on an iPhone 5s and lower (not an issue on iPhone6), the program crashes as it is trying to access a key in a dictionary that has been reallocated. (*EXC_BAD_ACCESS*)

This only happens when that string is longer than 6 characters. (!!)

I have my model that gets populated with data from an API call, and we then attempt to use it to populate fields on a view, specifically this line always fails:

`self.itemSubtitleLabel.text = itemModel.itemSubtitle;`

Now when I debug it I can see the NSDictionary `itemModel` has all the right data, but when we get to populating the view, the error occurs.

After doing a bit of reading I have been using instruments to catch that error. I collected the following details on that "Zombie" event but not sure what to do with it.

[image]

I'd like some help as to what next step I should take to fix this problem

## MORE CODE:

#### Model:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ItemModel.h"

@implementation ItemModel

+(ItemModel*)populateDataWithObject:(NSDictionary*)responseData {
    ItemModel *newItem          = [[ItemModel alloc] init];
    newItem.heading             = [responseData objectForKey:@"heading"];
    newItem.storyID             = [responseData objectForKey:@"storyID"];
    newItem.thumbnail           = [responseData objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
    newItem.itemSubtitle        = [responseData valueForKey:@"subtitle"];
    newItem.logo                = [responseData objectForKey:@"logo"];
    
    return newItem;
}


@end
```

### Calling API and populating cell:

```
/**
 * getting all items
 */
- (void)getAllItems:(BOOL)withLoader {
    if (withLoader) {
        [SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];
    }

    [[ItemManager sharedManager] getItems:nil Success:^(NSArray * array) {
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        allItemsArray = array;
        [self.itemsCollectionView reloadData];
        [refreshControl endRefreshing];
        reloadForFiltersSettings = NO;
        NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
    } failure:^(NSString *error) {
        NSLog(@"FAIL");
        reloadForFiltersSettings = NO;
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        [refreshControl endRefreshing];
        allItemsArray = nil;
        [self.itemsCollectionView reloadData];
        
        if ([error isEqualToString:@"401"]) {
            [self reLogin];
        } else {
            if (self.storyTypeBaseView.hidden == YES) {
                UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Nothing found"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                
                [alertView show];
            }
        }
    }];
}


/**
 * Loading items into cells for the "All" view
 */
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    
    ItemHeaderCell *cell = (ItemHeaderCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:ItemHeaderCellNib forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    ItemModel * itemModel = allItemsArray[indexPath.row];
    
    //loading data into cell
    [cell populateItemForCellWithData:itemModel withIndex: indexPath];
    
    if (itemModel.storyID) {
        cell.contentView.hidden = NO;
    } else {
        cell.contentView.hidden = YES;
    }
    
    return cell;
}
```

### ItemManager getItems:

```
- (void)getItems:(NSMutableDictionary*) param Success:(void (^)(NSArray *headerModel ))success failure:(void (^)(NSString *error))failure {
    if (![_baseManager isNetworkAvailable]) {
        [_baseManager noNetworkError: failure];
        return;
    }
    
    [_baseManager GET: GET_ITEMS parameters:param success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSArray * array = responseObject;
        
        if (array.count > 0) {
            NSMutableArray * mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            
            for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
                NSDictionary * dataDictionary = array[i];
                [mutableArray addObject:[ItemModel populateDataWithObject:dataDictionary]];
            }
            
            if (success) success(mutableArray);
        } else {
            failure(nil);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSString * statusCode = [_baseManager handleServerError: error withRequest: operation];
        
        if (failure) failure(statusCode);
    }];
}
```

### ItemHeaderCell:

```
-(void)populateItemForCellWithData:(ItemModel*)itemModel withIndex:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.itemTitleLabel applyAttributedText: itemModel.heading];
    self.itemSubtitleLabel.text = itemModel.itemSubtitle;
    
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
    
    NSString *docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSURL *urlPt = [NSURL URLWithString:itemModel.logo];
    NSString *path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[urlPt lastPathComponent]];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        UIImage *thumbNail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
        self.imageView.image =thumbNail;
    }

    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:itemModel.logo];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlReq=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    
    [self.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:urlReq placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        [self.imageView setImage:image];
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        
    }];
}
```

Comment: Step one: Use ARC! It does correct memory management for you. Step two: There is no step two. However, if you're having a problem only on iPhone 5s, this could indicate a threading issue of some sort. You have not shown any of your code (bad dog, no biscuit), but I do hope you are not trying to update the interface on a background thread, as that is strictly forbidden.

Comment: another weird thing is that if I step through it sometimes work. Will post more of the code (which we inherited)

Comment: Hey @matt thanks for your comment, can you elaborate on your `I do hope you are not trying to update the interface on a background thread, as that is strictly forbidden` please? Also we are using ARC, so not sure what's happening. I am aware that this is not the best codebase but like I said I inherited this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the property was set to `assign` instead of `strong` in my Model header file!

so changed

`@property (nonatomic,assign)   NSString *itemSubtitle;`

to

`@property (nonatomic,strong)   NSString *itemSubtitle;`

Thank you @matt for your help, at least it made me read about threads!